# Getting "Missing Error method" when migrating from GORM V1 to V2

Tags: go, orm, backend, go-gorm

I am currently in the process of migrating from GORM V1 to V2. There is a decent amount of backwards compatibility but I am facing the following issue.

```
config.DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(config.DBDSN), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

The code above shows how I connect to the mySQL db. The function below is causing an error.

```
func (b *Base) AddTags(model interface{}, modelID uint64, tagType models.TagType, tags []models.Tag) error {
    err := b.config.DB.Model(model).Association(tagType.Field()).Append(tags).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return b.updateTagPriority(model, modelID, tagType, tags)
}
```

The error is

> cannot use err (type func() string) as type error in return argument:
> func() string does not implement error (missing Error method)

I used the V2 release notes to refactor parts of the code but I can't figure out this particular issue. https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html I think there may be some significant change in error handling between V1 and V2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [code](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/bc347758e55b1c95a7f4c1eccfc9775f1736b901/association.go#L50), the `Append` function returns only a native `error`.

So you can write:

```
err := b.config.DB.Model(model).Association(tagType.Field()).Append(tags)
```

Instead of:

```
err := b.config.DB.Model(model).Association(tagType.Field()).Append(tags).Error
```